# Can you recognize this famous song from the '80s?

Tags: identify-this-song, guitar

So basically I've heard and recorded this guitar cover of a song. It's just one minute, I know I've heard it before but I can't come up with the title of this song!
I guess it's from the '80s, probably a rock ballad, but it could also be from the' 90s.. I can't be really sure about it unfortunately.

So if you want to give it a listen and try to help me, I'll link below the link of the audio I uploaded via Google drive.

Thanks for your attention! I'd be infinitely happy if you could tell me what song is it.
Have a good day :)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JHFKWDbabRd9w0GPEViYeqQqtrJKGDW1/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Welcome to the site. You'll be better served at 'Musicfans', as here we don't provide song titles. It's more 'Music:Practice and Theory', which is somewhat different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Stairway to Heaven" is a song by the English rock band Led Zeppelin, released in late 1971. It was composed by guitarist Jimmy Page and vocalist Robert Plant for the band's untitled fourth studio album (often called Led Zeppelin IV).

Comment: Also worth noting, it was once such a popular song for amateur guitarists to learn, that there's a gag in the movie *Wayne's World* about banning it from being played in guitar shops. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RD1KqbDdmuE

Comment: The song was/is subject of a [plagiarism lawsuit](https://www.theguardian.com/music/2018/sep/28/led-zeppelin-plagiarism-taurus-spirit-stairway-to-heaven-new-trial)  from a band who LZ had toured with :  but the LZ song is the one that people know, so your cover is not likely to be the song ['Taurus' by Spirit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xd8AVbwB_6E)  which uses a common "falling bass" minor chord riff anyway

Comment: @ChrisSunami That gag comes from real life.There was such a "meme" in music stores in the 1980's to groan or cringe at anyone busting out into Stairway. Clerks would indeed jokingly say, "that is not allowed here", or pretend to throw something at the guy (e.g. wave a pair of drumsticks in his direction, etc).  In the 90's, *Enter Sandman* took the song's place in this regard.

Comment: Okay, Ian.  The OP says the decade was 1980s.  The 1971 is part of the 19**7**0s.  The 1980s ran from 1981-1990.